# Convert MSDN Windows 7 Enterprise installation to Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

> **Related question:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

Unthinkingly I installed Windows 7 Enterprise on my development box at work rather than the Ultimate version.  Now windows is complaining that it is unable to activate because it can't contact a KMS (Key Management Service) which my company doesn't have.

Is there any way to change this install such that it believes it is Windows 7 Ultimate and will take an ultimate key?  I have MSDN so the licensing is not an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get an activation key from MSDN for the Enterprise edition that works fine to activate your installation over the Internet without changing editions. I used a partner activation key with Win7 Enterprise and it worked fine. It should be the same for MSDN. In fact, I can generate a key in the MSDN subscriber downloads website also.

Comment: slmgr -ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx from the command line is a quick way of activating.

Answer (score 2):

there is no 'Anytime Upgrade' path from Windows 7 Enterprise to Ultimate.

however, there is the old 'Vista trick' that might work with Windows 7.

> run
>   regedit.exe
>
> Navigate  to
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion
>
> Change the key **ProductName** from
>   "Windows Vista ™ Enterprise” to
>   “Windows Vista ™ Business”
>
> Change the key **EditionID** from
>   "Enterprise" to “Business”

change Enterprise to Home Basic, Home Premium, Professional or Starter. any of these versions allow for 'Anytime Upgrade'.

backup the registry keys before making changes.

Comment: I'm just downloading the ultimate iso now, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: sorry to hear, but as mentioned elsewhere, reinstalling windows 7 isn't such a big deal, in fact the windows migration tool should make it a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an official one.

You might try this:

http://www.msfn.org/board/upgrade-windows-vista-enterprise-ultimate-t96799.html

> There is a way to upgrade Windows Vista Enterprise to Ultimate (not enabled by default)
>
> Before inserting the Windows Vista Ultimate CD
>
> Go to, Start, Run: and type: regedit.exe
>
> Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
>
> Change the key : ProductName from "Windows Vista ™ Enterprise” to “Windows Vista ™ 
>   Business”
>
> Change the key: EditionID from "Enterprise" to “Business”

It's instructions for Vista, but it might work for 7 as well.

It also only takes around 30 minutes for a full reinstall anyway :).

Comment: 10 minutes here :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my enterprise version. My network admin provided me with a MAK (multiple activation key) which did the trick. According to MS, you are supposed to use the MAK keys up first before turning on the KMS.