# Will a Windows 7 Ultimate key work on Windows 7 Enterprise?

Tags: windows, licensing

I had work install a home copy of Windows 7 Enterprise edition on my laptop. I'm leaving the job, and I need to buy a copy of Windows. Most editions I'm able to find are Ultimate edition, not Enterprise edition. Would I be able to buy an Ultimate edition key and use it on Enterprise edition?

Comment: Related: [Convert MSDN Windows 7 Enterprise installation to Ultimate](http://superuser.com/questions/42250/convert-msdn-windows-7-enterprise-installation-to-ultimate)

Comment: If you are just looking to be legal call Microsoft, they will be more than happy to help.  Especially if you're looking to buy Ultimate. :)

Answer (score 3):

No.  The Windows 7 keys are specific to the hardware, computer manufacturer (assuming its pre-installed), and the version of Windows.